# linksys WRT350N dd-wrt: how can i give upload priority to slingbox?

Tags: router, streaming, dd-wrt, priority

I have the router WRT350N by Linksys.
I've installed dd-wrt v2.4 sp1 on it.

How can I configure it to give upload priority to slingbox?

The Slingbox is a TV streaming device that enables users to remotely view their home's cable.

It seems that slingbox streams to amazon ec2 servers and from there to the client so I can't really give priority based on ip-address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do it with [Quality of Service (QoS) rules](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Quality_of_Service). I expect you will do it by prioritising the Slingbox's MAC address.